# The total amount of precipitation for the year

Tags: python, csv, pathlib, import-csv

How do I write a program that reads the PRCP column and sums all values in it? We are using the import csv from pathlib import Path. Using python.
The answer should = 1

Example of info:

```
STATION NAME, DATE, PRCP, TMAX, TMIN
USW00023183PHOENIX AIRPORT, 1/1/2020, 1, 60, 40
USW00023183PHOENIX AIRPORT, 1/2/2020, 0, 64, 41
```

Tried:

```
prcps = 0
for item in prcps:
    month=item['DATE']
    prcps =(item["PRCP"])
    if prcps>0[month]:
        sum (prcps) 
perp = 0
for PRCP in reader:
    month = item['DATE']
    perp = (item["PRCP"])

    perp += perp
```

Comment: this is not a homework site btw

Comment: Read [this question on homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) - you need to show us that you've tried something before asking

Comment: Code placed in comments is normally unreadable.  Thus, code clarifying the question should always be added to the question, never comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's CSV library to read the CSV lines in. Each row is parsed as strings. So the `PRCP` value will first need to be converted into an integer using `int()`.

1. Using a `csv.reader()` which converts each row into a list:

   ```py
   import csv

   with open('input.csv') as f_input:
       csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
       header = next(csv_input)
       print(sum(int(row[2]) for row in csv_input))
   ```

   This first skips the header row and then extracts the third string value from each row, converts it into an integer and sums them.
2. Using a `csv.DictReader()` which assumes the first row is a header and then reads each row as a dictionary:

   ```py
   import csv

   with open('input.csv') as f_input:
       csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)
       print(sum(int(row["PRCP"]) for row in csv_input))
   ```

Comment: total = 0
    for item in date:
        total += item["PRCP"]
       / Worked for me but thank you for the reply.